# ERROR when setting precision and scale for BIGNUMERIC data type in Big Query schema using python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, dataproc

I am running my python code in a GCP DataProc cluster and using the *spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.24.2.jar* file. I am trying to create a table in BigQuery using the python client library as below:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery


client = bigquery.Client()

table_id = "some_project.some_dataset.some_table_name"
schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("full_name", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("salary", "BIGNUMERIC", precision=38, scale=2),
]

table = bigquery.Table(table_id, schema=schema)
table = client.create_table(table)
```

I get an error like this `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword 'precision'`

Comment: Hi Ethan, did my answer help you?

Comment: @Ethan Alberto Welcome to Stack Overflow! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Another option is to [upvote the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you feel it is useful for you There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This might be occurring because the object BIGNUMERIC does not have the correct values, you can try to use it in the following format

```
“BIGNUMERIC”, (38,2)
```

**Update:** *I replicated your issue and I was able to set up the precision and the scale for BIGNUMERIC, as mentioned it was due to the format you are calling it, could you try to run it but without the ( ), this seemed to be the issue, at least on my side.*

Comment: I get an error like this:
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has not attribute upper`

Comment: I will try to replicate the Stack Trace due to confidentiality issues:
`table = biquery.Table(table_id, schema)  
File ../.. line 380 in schema  
self._properties["schema"]={"fields": _build_schema_resource(value)}  
File ../.. line 380 in  _build_schema_resource  
return [field.to_api_repr() for field in fields]  
File ../.. line 380 in  schema.py  
"mode": self.mode.upper()`

Comment: Please let me know if the replication is successful.